# How to scan or query a Dynamodb table using Vogels by passing a JSON object of conditions?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, sails.js, adapter, vogels

I'm trying to implement a **custom sails-dynamodb adapter**, similar to [this one](https://github.com/gadelkareem/sails-dynamodb) but compatible with the new Sails version v1.0.

I got stuck  in implementing the find() function, trying to use the passed map of conditions (*the **query.criteria.where** parameter*), to build a dynamic query to the Dynamodb database using Vogels library.

**If I try building the query manually it works:**

```
model.scan().where('email').equals('xyz@abc.com').exec((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    sails.log.error(err);
  } else {
    sails.log.info(result);
  }
});
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is something similar to this:

```
model.scan({email: 'xyz@abc.com'}).exec((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    sails.log.error(err);
  } else {
    sails.log.info(result);
  }
});
```

---

*Sails version v1.0.2 

Vogels version v2.2.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a work around for this issue, where I'm iterating over the query's where conditions one by one, and appending them to the scanner object.

```
var _ = require('@sailshq/lodash');

let scanner = model.scan();

// Build query conditions
_.forOwn(sq3.criteria.where, (value, key) => {
  scanner.where(key).equals(value);
});

scanner.exec((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    sails.log.error(err);
  } else {
    sails.log.info(result);
  }
});
```